# Cookies are not being expired/removed in all browsers

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have set few cookies for my ecommerce website to keep track of users ordered items, if users choose to delete those items the cookies should also be deleted, however for some odd reason safari is not deleting those cookies. any other browser the cookies are being deleted fine.

Here is the link for the website if anyone wants to have a look: (link not available anymore) click on first item "blankets and towels" then choose any items from the 3 options, add it to card then go to basket, you should see on top left corner "numbers of cookies = 5" if u ordered more items it will increase, once all items is deleted from the cart it should say "numbers of cookies = 3" however in safari it still says 5.

Javascript

```
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item"))
    {
        var i = 1;
        while(true){
            var value = "; " + document.cookie;
            var parts = value.split("; " + "order"+i + "=");
            if(parts.length === 2){
                var results = parts.pop().split(";").shift();
                var temp = results.split(" ");
                if(temp[0] === id)
                {
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*60);
                    var exp = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                    var name = "order"+i;
                    temp[2] = temp[2] - 1; **REmove one item from order**
                    var val = temp[0] + " " + temp[1] + " " + temp[2];
                    if(temp[2] === 0){ **if cookie has 0 items then delete cookie**
                        document.cookie = name + "=" + '' + ";" + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;'+ ";path=/";
                        setNewTotal();
                    }else{
                        document.cookie = name + "=" + val + ";" + exp + ";path=/";
                        setNewTotal();
                    }
                    window.location.reload(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        window.location.reload(false);
    }else{

    }
}
function setNewTotal(){
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + "totalOrders=");
    if(parts.length === 2) {
        var results =  parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    }
    results = results - 1;
    var d = new Date();
    if(results === 0){
        document.cookie = "totalOrders=" + '' + ";" + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;' + ";path=/";
    }else{
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*60);
        var exp = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "totalOrders=" + results + ";" + exp + ";path=/";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out when deleting the cookies I specified the time wrong, seems all other browsers ignored it except safari.

old code:

```
  document.cookie = "totalOrders=" + '' + ";" + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;' + ";path=/";
```

New code

```
 document.cookie = "totalOrders=" + '' + ";" + 'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC;' + ";path=/";
```

Notice that **'=;expires=Thu,'** was replaced with **'expires=Thu,'** this is because I had already set  **= "totalOrders=" + '' + ";"** therefore there was no need for **=;**

Thank you for the help very appreciate :)